# Linkedlist While loop (python), why we are doing fast.next in while loop instead of fast.next.next

Tags: python, linked-list

```
slow = self.head
fast = self.head

while fast and fast.next:
    slow = slow.next
    fast = fast.next.next
 
print("The middle element is ", slow.data)"
```

**Middle Element** *Fast.next.next*> Help

Comment: I do not understand your question, it isn't clear what oyu are referring to exactly. Please see [ask] and the [help]

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` condition we need to test `fast.next` so that we don't try to access `fast.next.next` when `fast.next` is `None`.

We don't need to test `fast.next.next` there, because that will be tested on the next iteration, after we do `fast = fast.next.next`.